# create menu with ionic 2 and angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am developing a mobile application with ionic 2, and I need a menu as shown in the image,this menu is not like the menu side

[Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CDRa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to scaffold a new project with ionic2 cli using

```
$ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

which will give you the basic hamburger menu after which it is all on how you style it.

Comment: Not the side menu, I need something else
thank you for your reply